# How to add the content of file A into file B between the pattern match

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have two files:

This is the content of file A:

```
etc...
this is a test file having \@ and \# and \$ as well
looking for awk or sed solution to print this content in another file between the matching pattern
etc....
```

This is the content of file B:

```
file-B begin 
this is a large file containing many patterns like 
pattern-1 
pattern-2 
pattern-2 
pattern-3 
pattern-2 
pattern-4 
file-B end
```

I want the output of file B as:

```
file-B begin 
this is a large file containing many patterns like 
pattern-1 
pattern-2 
pattern-2 
etc... 
this is a test file having \@ and \# and \$ as well 
looking for awk or sed solution to print this content in another file between the matching pattern 
etc.... 
pattern-3 
pattern-2 
pattern-4 
file-B end
```

I want to print the content of file A between the pattern-2 and pattern-3 of file B.

Currently, I am using this:

```
awk '/pattern-2/{c++;if(c==2){printf $0; print "\n"; while(getline line<"file-A"){print line};next}}1' file-B
```

and it is working fine but, I need something that searches both the pattern and then puts another file content between them.

Answer (score 3):

```
awk -v file="file-A" '
  last=="pattern-2" && $0=="pattern-3"{
    while ((getline line < file)>0) print line
    close(file)
  }
  {last=$0}1
' file-B
```

Or if you use regex patterns instead of strings, use something like

```
  last ~ /pattern-2/ && /pattern-3/{
```

in the second line.

Comment: Thanks Freddy for quick reply. But it is not working. did you tried this command on your system?.

Comment: Make sure you don't have any space characters/tabs at the line endings of file-B or the string comparison will fail (or use `$1` instead of `$0`).

Comment: regex part is working i.e   last ~ /pattern-2/ && /pattern-3/{

Comment: Yes, if I copy & paste `file-B` from your example, then there are extra space characters I need to remove. You can see them with `cat -A file-B` (the `$` is the end of the line).

Comment: Since the above command is changing the output inside the terminal. Now I want to change the file as. What to do in that case? or can you give me sed command as well for above?

Comment: You can redirect the output to a new file with `awk ... file-B > newfile` and then overwrite the file with `mv newfile file-B`.

Comment: Thanks @freddy it worked :)